# Python: wrapping recursive functions

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

How can I wrap a recursive function, recursive calls included? For example, given `foo` and `wrap`:

```
def foo(x):
    return foo(x - 1) if x > 0 else 1

def wrap(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print "f was called"
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped
```

`wrap(foo)(x)` will only output `"f was called"` with the first call. Recursive calls still address `foo()`.

I don't mind monkey patching, or poking around internals. I'm not planning to add this code to the next nuclear warhead handling program, so even if it's a bad idea, I'd like to achieve the effect.

**Edit**: for example, would patching `foo.func_globals` to override `foo.__name__` work? If it always does, any side-effects I should be minding?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works if you use your wrapper function as a decorator.

```
def wrap(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print "f was called"
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

@wrap
def foo(x):
    return foo(x - 1) if x > 0 else 1
```

Reason being that in your example, you're only calling the result of the `wrap` function once. If you use it as a decorator it actually replaces the definition of `foo` in the module namespace with the decorated function, so its internal call resolves to the wrapped version.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? Haha! Fantastic. Thanks.

Comment: actually in your original example if you used foo = wrap(foo) and then called foo(5), it would also do the equivalent thing :)  But decorator syntax is the clearer way to do that.

Comment: This will work, but is there a way to do it without overwriting the original name in the namespace? @brandizzi didn't forget, there's a minimum time before accepting :)

Comment: No, there's no way to do it without overwriting the original name in the namespace. You are calling the function by name; to call the wrap function rather than the original by that name, the wrap function *must* replace the original in the namespace.

Comment: @kindall In fact, it could be done by explisitly passing a wrapper to `foo`. But this [looks super-ugly](http://ideone.com/kBU7p)!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the function with a class, rather than a function:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...     return foo(x-1) if x > 0 else 1
...
>>> class Wrap(object):
...     def __init__(self, f): self.f = f
...     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         print "f called"
...         return self.f(*args, **kwargs)
...
>>> foo = Wrap(foo)
>>> foo(4)
f called
1
```

Comment: That's exactly what I **didn't** want! xD

Comment: It is not needed to wrap the function in a class - a function decorator would work as well. It did not work in the OP example because one should bind the wrapped function to the original name, as in @Kamil answer.

Comment: Ohhhh haha I just reread the question. I thought you wanted the wrapper function to be executed ONLY once :P. Yeah, Kamil's answer works nicely for that.